# What does orange mean in Glimpse's SQL tab?

Tags: glimpse

In the [Glimpse SQL tab](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/sql-tab), some of the stored procedures called are orange. What does this signify? The tab details don't seem to say what that means.

I am using Glimpse.MVC5 and Glimpse.ADO, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, see Why are some commands in [Glimpse's SQL tab orange with an exclamation icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661776/why-are-some-commands-in-glimpses-sql-tab-orange-with-an-exclamation-icon)

I downloaded the Glimpse code and answered my own question. Here's the short of it:

> Glimpse.Ado maintains a dictionary that tracks the number of times each particular command text has been executed during the lifetime of a web request. Any command texts that have been executed previously in the web request are marked as duplicate and these duplicate requests are colored orange in the Sql tab.

Here's [a direct link to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709052/160830), with more details.

Answer (score 0):

It appears those mean that transactions are left open, as I gathered from [this rather old issue](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/435).